# Python: How do I read and parse a unicode utf-8 text file?

Tags: python, xml, unicode, parsing, codec

I am exporting UTF-8 text from Excel and I want to read and parse the incoming data using Python. I've read all the online info so I've already tried this, for example:

```
 txtFile = codecs.open( 'halout.txt', 'r', 'utf-8' )
 for line in txtFile:
  print repr( line )
```

The error I am getting is:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: unexpected code byte

Looking at the text file in a Hex editor, the first values are FFFE I've also tried:

```
txtFile.seek( 2 )
```

right after the 'open' but that just causes a different error.

Comment: Somehow the text you are exporting is not in the UTF-8 *encoding* but it might be in a different encoding of Unicode, for example UTF-16. These are all distinct. There is much to know about this subject! If you read both of these, you will master this like never before: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html http://www.amk.ca/python/howto/unicode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark)

EDIT, from the coments, it seems to be a utf-16 bom

```
codecs.open('foo.txt', 'r', 'utf-16')
```

should work.

Comment: From the Wikipedia page you've linked: "The UTF-8 representation of the BOM is the byte sequence EF BB BF" -- therefore the file is not in UTF-8 (due to OP sees FFFE it is a UTF-16 in little-endian order).

Comment: Fails: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: unexpected code byte"

Answer (score 5):

That file is not UTF-8; it's [UTF-16LE with a byte-order marker](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM).

Comment: Amazing psychic powers there!

Comment: How do you distinguish UTF-16LE from UTF-32LE using only the first 2 bytes?

Comment: Good point; one can't. I've never encountered UTF-32 in a file, but I'm sure it has happened. Once. On crack.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Johnathan's comment, this code should read the file correctly:

```
import codecs
txtFile = codecs.open( 'halout.txt', 'r', 'utf-16' )
for line in txtFile:
   print repr( line )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if the excel file has some blank rows (and then has values again), that might cause the unexpected error.